# android app doesn't run on Samsung gt -s5830

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

The build target of my app is Google API 2.2 and it does run perfectly on eclipse emulator but when I run it from the device ( Samsung gt s5830 with android 2.3.5) I get 'force close' when the app makes an http request (apache-mysql-php), the json arrays returned is null.
    E/Buffer Error(1677): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
    E/JSON Parser(1677): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
    E/AndroidRuntime(1677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Please if you have any ideas, help..(has it to do with any device settings? I have the "Usb debugging", "gps", "data synchronization", "internet connection" )

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the [uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) for Android.Hardware.Wifi in the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

It force closes because you are just assuming that the json you get back is good and it's not.  That's why it's giving you a parser exception.  You need to add better error handling because you can't count on a mobile device to have a consistant connection to a network.

That said we'll need more information to try to help you figure out why your json is invalid.  What url are you trying to pull the data from?

Answer (score 0):

Beyond any other causal problem resulting in a null response from your php output, you have failed to reliably test the output before pushing it through the JSONParser.

Make sure that you validate your return data before trying to pass it.

This could be as simple as:

```
if(myJsonData!=null)
{
   //parse the json
}
else
{
   //do something useful here
}
```

You should be catching any exceptions in your download code that provide you more information.

You can do this using try/catch blocks.

Also learn about how to use logcat with your device to debug the code and find out what the cause is.  Any other method is guesswork.